# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.EnableSsl.get

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

Can anyone help me with correcting this error? I'm basically trying to make a personal email client to get more familiar with the language, but I can't seem to find out how to resolve the  issue. Here's the code.

```
 private void fusionButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String One = textBox1.Text;
        String Two = textBox2.Text;
        String Three = textBox3.Text;
        String Four = textBox4.Text;
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("Sender@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(String.Copy(Four)));
        message.Subject = String.Copy(Three);
        message.Body = String.Copy(One); String.Copy(Two);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.Send(message);
        NetworkCredential netCre = new NetworkCredential("Sender@gmail.com", "Pass");
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

instead of this:

```
SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

You are referencing Non-static property [`EnableSsl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx) as static.

**NOTE**:

You don't need to use `String.Copy`:

```
message.Subject = String.Copy(Three);
```

You could directly use this:

```
message.Subject = textBox3.Text; 
message.Body = textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text;
```

Try this code:

```
private void fusionButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress("Sender@gmail.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox4.Text));
    message.Subject =  textBox3.Text;
    message.Body =  textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text; 

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);       
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Sender@gmail.com", "Pass");        
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(message);
 }
```

Comment: That worked, but now it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. f65sm3327693yhp.14 - gsmtp"

Any Ideas on that?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works now. I'm going to review it and see if I can tell where I messed up and where this fixed it. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Welcome. For the message body you can always format email content. For example you could use HTML tags for formatting like `message.Body = textBox1.Text + "<BR/><BR/>" + textBox2.Text;`. It will show two line breaks. Explore it. Also you could mark this as an answer.